# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint' in controller test

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator, controller-tests

I wrote a controller which combines actuator info.

```java
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class AppStatusRestController {
    private final HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;
    private final InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint;

    public AppStatusRestController(HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint, InfoEndpoint infoEndpoint) {
        this.healthEndpoint = healthEndpoint;
        this.infoEndpoint = infoEndpoint;
    }

    @GetMapping("/status")
    public Status status() {
        Map<String, Object> info = infoEndpoint.info();
        return Status.builder()
                .status(healthEndpoint.health().getStatus().getCode())
                .appName("My application")
                .version(((Map<String, Object>) info.get("build")).get("version").toString())
                .buildDateTime(((Map<String, Object>) info.get("build")).get("timestamp").toString())
                .build();
    }
}
```

In my test I get an error `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint'`.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = AppStatusRestController.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*")
class AppStatusRestControllerTest {

    @Test
    void status() {
    }
}
```

How can I actiavate default spring actuator beans in controller test(`@SpringBootTest`/`@WebMvcTest`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess *I'm narrowing down the context* is the answer to your question: Spring includes only the controller into its context skipping everything else. Try to include `HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration` too.

Comment: Please note that I'm trying to test only part of a bigger application that's why I'm narrowing down the context to `classes = AppStatusRestController.class` when I add this to your solution it doesn't work, and instead of exposing the app on random port I want to use mockMvc `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`

Comment: Then I guess "I'm narrowing down the context" is the answer to your question: Spring includes only the controller into its context skipping everything else. Try to include `HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration` too.

Comment: It solved the no qualifying bean problem but mockMvc returns empty string but that wasn't my original question. Please include HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration in your answer, the one you wrote is wrong.

Comment: Done. As of empty string I'd suggest to debug the endpoint, the issue could be about `HealthContributor` that supplies the endpoint with data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@SpringBootTest()` with no classes and it will work too. In this case, Spring will load the full context for executing the tests.

```
@SpringBootTest()
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info" })
class AppStatusRestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void version() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/status")).andReturn();
        String contentAsString = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Status result = objectMapper.readValue(contentAsString, Status.class);
        assertEquals(result.getStatus(), "UP");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but my point was that I want to test the controller class only, without loading whole application for this test.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by creating `TestApplication.java` which includes only one controller of my application. Then I'm testing by loading test app into context `@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)`.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(AppStatusRestController.class)
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info" })
class AppStatusRestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void version() throws Exception {
        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/status")).andReturn();
        String contentAsString = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Status result = objectMapper.readValue(contentAsString, Status.class);
        assertEquals(result.getStatus(), "UP");
    }
}
```